# Dart 2.3 ignores breakpoints

Tags: webstorm, dart-pub, dart

I am developing a web app in Dart using Webstorm as IDE. After upgrading from Dart SDK 2.2 to Dart SDK 2.3 I noticed that all breakpoints I set in Webstorm are ignored (although the app seems to run properly in Chrome) That breakpoints are correctly marked as a "red circle" but unlike the previous SDK they miss the "tick" inside (which I think means they are not recognized by Chrome).

I tried to "repair cache" and "upgrade dependencies" but breakpoints still don't work.

That's the pubspec.yaml dev_dependencies:

```
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.4.0
  build_test: ^0.10.7+3
  build_web_compilers: ^2.1.0
```

Here is the "webdev serve" command:

```
/dart/2.3.1/dart-sdk/bin/pub global run webdev serve web:53321
```

Here is the "webdev serve" command result:

```
[INFO] Serving `web` on http://localhost:53321
[INFO] Running build completed, took 351ms
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 177ms
[INFO] Succeeded after 536ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)
```

Here the versions of envolved softwares:

```
- O.S.: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
- Chrome: 74.0.3729.169
- Webstorm: 2019.1 - Build 191.7141.49
- Dart SDK: 2.3.1
- Dart webdev: 2.0.5
```

I'm trying to figure out if the issue is related to Webstorm, Dart SDK or Chrome. I don't exclude that I miss some new configuration due to the Dart SDK upgrade. Downgrading back to Dart SDK 2.2 everything works fine. Thank you for your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproduced, logged as [WEB-39095](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39095). Please follow it for updates

Answer (score 1):

The bug was in [webdev](https://pub.dev/packages/webdev) 2.0.0 - 2.0.6. It is fixed in webdev 2.0.7. You may run `pub global activate webdev` to get the latest version. You might need to close/open the project in the IDE to get it working.